# how to change an element type using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the the following code

```
<b class="xyzxterms" style="cursor: default; ">bryant keil bio</b>
```

How would I replace the `b` tag to a `h1` tag but keep all other attributes and information?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Comment: @beanland: This does not keep the attributes.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it with jQuery:

```
var attrs = { };

$.each($("b")[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
    attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
});


$("b").replaceWith(function () {
    return $("<h1 />", attrs).append($(this).contents());
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yapHk/

**Update**, here's a plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
        var attrs = {};

        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
        });

        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mmNNJ/

Comment: +1 Nice. Regarding the content, you can do: `$("<h1 />", attrs).append($(this).children());`. This would also preserve any data and event handlers attached to child nodes.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks, `children` didn't work but `contents` did.

Comment: Ah right... it had to be `.contents()`, forgot about the text nodes.

Comment: i just noticed there are other b tags that get changed is is possible to change based on class?

Comment: @bammab: sure, you would change all the instances of `"b"` to `"b.class`". One second and I'll wrap it in a plugin.

Comment: @bammab: There's a plugin that will do it. You can use `$("b.class").changeElementType("h1");`

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker WOW!!! you're good! So just to be sure I use b.class or b.xyzxterms (xyzxterms being the name of the class)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: Where's the plugin?

Comment: @qwertymk: The code wrapped with `(function($) { ... })(jQuery)`

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: If I'm not wrong, in your plugin, the attributes of the first matched element will be applied to all matching elements. It's not necessarily what we want. Also an error is raise when there's not matched element in the set. Here's a modified version of your plugin that keep own attributes for each matched elements and do not trigger an error on empty set: https://gist.github.com/2934516

Comment: @Etienne: Yes, I think you're right in both cases. Thanks for the update!

Comment: This works like a charm! Except that when the selector fails to find any matching element, it throws an error message to console because this[0] is undefined accessing attributes breaks. Adding a condition fixes it: 
if (this.length != 0) {...

Comment: @ciuncan: Thanks for the feedback! It should really be wrapped in an `.each` block like an answer below shows too.

Comment: Can someone explain to me what's going on with the $.each() there?

Comment: @MetalPhoenix Late response, but in case it helps anyone: That's the jQuery $.each function, documented at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ and is *not* the same as jQuery $(selector).each() function. It's taking the attribute array and iterating over it. Worth reiterating: For the general case, people should use Eitienne's Gist version, since that reads the attributes of each separate element, instead of relying on the attribute array of the first matched element.

Comment: "attribute array and iterating over it" Gotcha. I'd never seen it written that way where the collection was inside the .each, always $("something").each(function(){}); Thanks

Comment: Goodness, why is this not built into jQuery yet? Seems a very useful DOM manipulation when you're, say, working with third party HTML. Plugin is simple enough, though, tnx.

Answer (score 17):

Not sure about jQuery. With plain JavaScript you could do:

```
var new_element = document.createElement('h1'),
    old_attributes = element.attributes,
    new_attributes = new_element.attributes;

// copy attributes
for(var i = 0, len = old_attributes.length; i < len; i++) {
    new_attributes.setNamedItem(old_attributes.item(i).cloneNode());
}

// copy child nodes
do {
    new_element.appendChild(element.firstChild);
} 
while(element.firstChild);

// replace element
element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, element);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5NHvw/1/)

Not sure how cross-browser compatible this is though.

A variation could be:

```
for(var i = 0, len = old_attributes.length; i < len; i++) {
    new_element.setAttribute(old_attributes[i].name, old_attributes[i].value);
}
```

For more information see [`Node.attributes` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.attributes).

Comment: The performance of your code is better than the "pure jQuery" (ex. Andrew's code), but have a little problem with inner tags, see italic at [this example with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/5NHvw/17/) and the [reference-example](http://jsfiddle.net/mmNNJ/194/).

Comment: If you correct, [an "ideal jquery plugin"](http://jsfiddle.net/mmNNJ/195/) can be defined, calling your function by the jquery-plugin-template.

Comment: Fixed. The problem was that after the copying over the first child, it doesn't have a next sibling anymore, so `while(child = child.nextSibling)` failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

@jakov and @Andrew Whitaker

Here is a further improvement so it can handle multiple elements at once.

```
$.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
    var newElements = [];

    $(this).each(function() {
        var attrs = {};

        $.each(this.attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
        });

        var newElement = $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());

        $(this).replaceWith(newElement);

        newElements.push(newElement);
    });

    return $(newElements);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

@Jazzbo's answer returned a jQuery object containing an array of jQuery objects, which wasn't chainable. I've changed it so that it returns an object more similar to what $.each would have returned:

```
    $.fn.changeElementType = function (newType) {
        var newElements,
            attrs,
            newElement;

        this.each(function () {
            attrs = {};

            $.each(this.attributes, function () {
                attrs[this.nodeName] = this.nodeValue;
            });

            newElement = $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());

            $(this).replaceWith(newElement);

            if (!newElements) {
                newElements = newElement;
            } else {
                $.merge(newElements, newElement);
            }
        });

        return $(newElements);
    };
```

(Also did some code cleanup so it passes jslint.)

Comment: This seems like the nicest option. The only thing I don't get is why you moved the var declaration for attrs out of the this.each(). It works fine with it left there: http://jsfiddle.net/9c0k82sr/1/

Comment: I grouped the vars because of jslint: "(Also did some code cleanup so it passes jslint.)". The idea behind that is to make the code faster, i think (not having to redeclare vars within each `each` loop).

Answer (score 2):

Only way I can think of is to copy everything over manually: [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/2X63R/)

**HTML**

```
<b class="xyzxterms" style="cursor: default; ">bryant keil bio</b>
```

**Jquery/Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var me = $("b");
    var newMe = $("<h1>");
    for(var i=0; i<me[0].attributes.length; i++) {
        var myAttr = me[0].attributes[i].nodeName;
        var myAttrVal = me[0].attributes[i].nodeValue;
        newMe.attr(myAttr, myAttrVal);
    }
    newMe.html(me.html());
    me.replaceWith(newMe);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@Andrew Whitaker: I propose this change:

```
$.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
    var attrs = {};

    $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
        attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
    });

    var newelement = $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
    this.replaceWith(newelement);
    return newelement;
};
```

Then you can do things like: `$('<div>blah</div>').changeElementType('pre').addClass('myclass');`

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of @AndrewWhitaker and others, to use a jQuery plugin -- to add the `changeElementType()` method. But a plugin is like a blackbox, no mater about the code, if it is litle and works fine... So, performance is required, and is most important than code.

"Pure javascript" have **better performance** than jQuery: I think that @FelixKling's code have better performance than @AndrewWhitaker's and others.

---

[Here a "pure Javavascript" (and "pure DOM") code, encapsulated into a jQuery plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/SN2hd/):

```js
 (function($) {  // @FelixKling's code
    $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
      for (var k=0;k<this.length; k++) {
       var e = this[k];
       var new_element = document.createElement(newType),
        old_attributes = e.attributes,
        new_attributes = new_element.attributes,
        child = e.firstChild;
       for(var i = 0, len = old_attributes.length; i < len; i++) {
        new_attributes.setNamedItem(old_attributes.item(i).cloneNode());
       }
       do {
        new_element.appendChild(e.firstChild);
       }
       while(e.firstChild);
       e.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, e);
      }
      return this; // for chain... $(this)?  not working with multiple 
    }
 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method I use to replace html tags in jquery:

```
// Iterate over each element and replace the tag while maintaining attributes
$('b.xyzxterms').each(function() {

  // Create a new element and assign it attributes from the current element
  var NewElement = $("<h1 />");
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
    $(NewElement).attr(attrib.name, attrib.value);
  });

  // Replace the current element with the new one and carry over the contents
  $(this).replaceWith(function () {
    return $(NewElement).append($(this).contents());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

### With `jQuery` *without* iterating over attributes:

The `replaceElem` method below accepts `old Tag`, `new Tag` and `context` and executes the replacement successfully:

---

```js
replaceElem('h2', 'h1', '#test');

function replaceElem(oldElem, newElem, ctx) {
  oldElems = $(oldElem, ctx);
  //
  $.each(oldElems, function(idx, el) {
    var outerHTML, newOuterHTML, regexOpeningTag, regexClosingTag, tagName;
    // create RegExp dynamically for opening and closing tags
    tagName = $(el).get(0).tagName;
    regexOpeningTag = new RegExp('^<' + tagName, 'i'); 
    regexClosingTag = new RegExp(tagName + '>$', 'i');
    // fetch the outer elem with vanilla JS,
    outerHTML = el.outerHTML;
    // start replacing opening tag
    newOuterHTML = outerHTML.replace(regexOpeningTag, '<' + newElem);
    // continue replacing closing tag
    newOuterHTML = newOuterHTML.replace(regexClosingTag, newElem + '>');
    // replace the old elem with the new elem-string
    $(el).replaceWith(newOuterHTML);
  });

}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  content: 'this is h1';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="test">
  <h2>Foo</h2>
  <h2>Bar</h2>
</div>
```

Good Luck...

Comment: I like your answer!  Why?  Because ALL of the other answers will fail in attempting to do something simple like convert an anchor to a label.  That said, please consider the following fixes/revisions to your answer:  A).  Your code won't work with selectors.  B)  Your code needs to perform case insensitive regex.  That said, here are my suggested fixes:  regexOpeningTag = new RegExp('^<' + $(el).get(0).tagName, 'i');    regexClosingTag = new RegExp($(el).get(0).tagName + '>$', 'i');

Comment: Replacing plain HTML like this will also make you lose any event listeners attached to the objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript solution**

Copy the attributes of old element to the new element

```
const $oldElem = document.querySelector('.old')
const $newElem = document.createElement('div')

Array.from($oldElem.attributes).map(a => {
  $newElem.setAttribute(a.name, a.value)
})
```

Replace the old element with the new element

```
$oldElem.parentNode.replaceChild($newElem, $oldElem)
```

Comment: `map` creates a new unused array, it could be replaced by `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version. It's basically @fiskhandlarn's version, but instead of constructing a new jQuery object, it simply overwrites the old elements with the newly created ones, so no merging is necessary.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0qa7wL1b/

```
$.fn.changeElementType = function( newType ){
  var $this = this;

  this.each( function( index ){

    var atts = {};
    $.each( this.attributes, function(){
      atts[ this.name ] = this.value;
    });

    var $old = $(this);
    var $new = $('<'+ newType +'/>', atts ).append( $old.contents() );
    $old.replaceWith( $new );

    $this[ index ] = $new[0];
  });

  return this;
};
```