# Replace a tag with span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace a tag with span tag using javascript or jquery in the below mentioned code.

```
<a class="multi-choice-btn" id="abcd123">
     <img class="x-panel-inline-icon feedback-icon " src="../images/choice_correct.png" id="pqrs123">
</a>
```

This should be changed as below.

```
<span class="multi-choice-btn" id="abcd123">
     <img class="x-panel-inline-icon feedback-icon " src="../images/choice_correct.png" id="pqrs123">
</span>
```

Replacement has to be done on basis of class "multi-choice-btn" as id will be dynamic.

Please help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this? (none of my business I know).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change an element type using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("abcd123"),
    span = document.createElement("span");

span.innerHTML = anchor.innerHTML;
span.className = anchor.className;
span.id = anchor.id;

anchor.parentNode.replaceChild(span,anchor);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tCyVH/

Comment: Does it has a set too? I thought it could only return.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as following:

```
$('a').contents().unwrap().wrap('<span></span>');​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XzYdu/

If you want to keep the attribute you can do as following:

```
// New type of the tag
var replacementTag = 'span';

// Replace all a tags with the type of replacementTag
$('a').each(function() {
    var outer = this.outerHTML;

    // Replace opening tag
    var regex = new RegExp('<' + this.tagName, 'i');
    var newTag = outer.replace(regex, '<' + replacementTag);

    // Replace closing tag
    regex = new RegExp('</' + this.tagName, 'i');
    newTag = newTag.replace(regex, '</' + replacementTag);

    $(this).replaceWith(newTag);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XzYdu/1/

Comment: You'll loose all attributes from the `<a>`-tag.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. This is prone to fail. The browser is the perfect environment to manipulate the DOM, there is no need to fall back to string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Not the shortest but working:

```
$('.multi-choice-btn').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<span>', {
        id: this.id,
        `class`: this.className,
        html: $(this).html()
    })
});​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/unVfp/

Answer (score 1):

Try using replaceWith and a small attrCopy logic. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4HWPC/

```
$('.multi-choice-btn').replaceWith(function() {

    var attrCopy = {};
    for (var i = 0, attrs = this.attributes, l = attrs.length; i < l; i++) {
        attrCopy[attrs.item(i).nodeName] = attrs.item(i).nodeValue;
    }       

    return $('<span>').attr(attrCopy).html($(this).html());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this attached [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/TVneM/1/).

```
var props = $(".multi-choice-btn").prop("attributes");

var span = $("<span>");

$.each(props, function() {
    span.attr(this.name, this.value);
});

$(".multi-choice-btn").children().unwrap().wrapAll(span);​
```