# change the html element from div to ul using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm new in jquery

i want to change any div contains those classes to those unformatted lists :

> .view-content -----> 'ul'
>
> .view-row ----> 'li'
>
> .view-organigramme-departements ---> '`<ul><li></li></ul>`'

the source :

```
<div class="view-content"><!-- <UL> -->

    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first"><!-- <LI> -->
        <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/op%C3%A9ration-0">Opération</a>    
        <div class="view view-organigramme-departements view-id-organigramme_departements view-display-id-default view-dom-id-401dc87ab045747942dc42b9669bd629"><!-- <ul><li> -->
            <div class="view-content"><!-- <UL> -->
                <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last"><!-- <LI> -->
                    <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/it-delivery-0">- IT delivery</a>    
                    <div class="view view-organigramme view-id-organigramme view-display-id-default view-dom-id-649f1ec1753ed6a97c093f67f2d6dcfc">
                        <div class="view-content"><!-- <UL> -->
                            <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last"><!-- <LI> -->
                                <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/amo-0">--AMO</a>    
                                Chef du service:     HAKKAL Sanaa    
                            </div><!-- <LI> -->
                        </div><!-- </UL> -->
                    </div>
                </div><!-- </LI> -->
            </div><!-- </UL> -->
        </div>   <!-- </ul></li> --> 
    </div><!-- </LI> -->
    
    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">
        <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/sinistre">Sinistre</a>    
        <div class="view view-organigramme-departements view-id-organigramme_departements view-display-id-default view-dom-id-c67ab28c33a24e8d6cef2bb463d98c1b">
            <div class="view-content">
                <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                    <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/dept-sinistre">- Dept. Sinistre</a>    
                    <div class="view view-organigramme view-id-organigramme view-display-id-default view-dom-id-9f02698becf34ce2d341fa2b8c1155ef">
                        <div class="view-content">
                            <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                                <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/service-sinistre">--Service Sinistre</a>    
                                Chef du service:     Validateur IT
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div><!-- </UL> -->
```

desired Outcome :

```
<ul class="view-content">
    <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/op%C3%A9ration-0">Opération</a>    
        <ul class="view view-organigramme-departements view-id-organigramme_departements view-display-id-default view-dom-id-401dc87ab045747942dc42b9669bd629">
            <li>
                <ul class="view-content">
                    <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                        <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/it-delivery-0">- IT delivery</a>    
                        <ul class="view view-organigramme view-id-organigramme view-display-id-default view-dom-id-649f1ec1753ed6a97c093f67f2d6dcfc">
                            <li>
                                <ul class="view-content">
                                    <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                                        <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/amo-0">--AMO</a>    
                                        Chef du service:     HAKKAL Sanaa    
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    
    <li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">
        <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/sinistre">Sinistre</a>    
        <ul class="view view-organigramme-departements view-id-organigramme_departements view-display-id-default view-dom-id-c67ab28c33a24e8d6cef2bb463d98c1b">
            <li>
                <ul class="view-content">
                    <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                        <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/dept-sinistre">- Dept. Sinistre</a>    
                        <ul class="view view-organigramme view-id-organigramme view-display-id-default view-dom-id-9f02698becf34ce2d341fa2b8c1155ef">
                            <li>
                                <ul class="view-content">
                                    <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                                    <a href="/ZurichIntranetProd/content/service-sinistre">--Service Sinistre</a>    
                                        Chef du service:     Validateur IT
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
</ul>
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to do this with javascript? You could just replace it all at once using `Find and Replace` tool in Dreamweaver, Notepad++, Word, take your pick. Sounds much easier and less load for the client.

Comment: Any specific reason you could not create a simplest test case?

Comment: @kcdwayne i'm using drupal 7 , so i just can't get the page

Comment: @roXon this is it : http://jsfiddle.net/g5J6r/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has already been answered here - [how to change an element type using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery)
Just create a function to iterate over your divs.

Comment: lol... that's the exact same answer which I linked in my answer, except that this answer is just a link, and mine actually shows you how to solve YOUR situation. Why the unaccept?

Answer (score 3):

The following will do what you're looking for:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {
        var attrs = {};
        if (!(this[0] && this[0].attributes))
            return;

        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
        });
        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$('.view-row').changeElementType('li');
$('.view-content').changeElementType('ul');
$('.view-organigramme-departements').wrap('<ul />').changeElementType('li');
```

Note that the plugin code is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584217/1454806). For a working example, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7L59/).

Comment: this is so simple to use , great post buddy ^^