# How can I style an HTML select element in function of the number of options it has?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I would like to do is to change the style of a select box in function of the number of options that it has. More specifically, I would like it to look like a `span` when there's only one option, and like a typical `select` element otherwise. In other words, I would like to hide the possibility of making a choice when there is no choice to make.

So far, the only solution I've found to this is to change the type of the tag back and forth from `select` to `span`, using jQuery and another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery), but since this is rather about styling, I would like to know about a pure CSS solution (or at least, CSS + jQuery solution).

Comment: When there's no choice to make, make it disabled.

Comment: @tymeJV When there's no choice, why not add a class instead?

Comment: @tymeJV that doesn't really change the style. It just disables it.

Comment: @jumpingcode That direction seems good, I tried that, but I don't know how to write CSS to define the style of that class in order to make a select element look like a span, say.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan I want to know about the possibility of doing it, overall. I didn't tried to write code since I didn't know where I was heading.

Comment: @jumpingcode I accepted your answer since I think is the one that most directly addresses the question I was asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fKEJt/2/)***

### CSS

```
select { 
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font: inherit; 
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

select:focus {
    outline:none; 
    outline-offset:0; 
}

select > option {
    display:none; 
}
```

These select styles should only be applied to a `<select>` element with only one `<option>`

***[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KT6Tw/1/)***

### jQuery

```
$('select').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).children().length == 1) {
        $(el).css("display", "none"); // Hide it
        var optionVal = $(el).children().eq(0).text();
        $(el).after($("<span>" + optionVal + "</span>"));
    }
});
```

This will loop through every `<select>` on your page and then check if it has one option. If it does, it will hide the select and insert a span after.

Comment: it's not a crossbrowser solution this only works fine in google chrome

Comment: Great @jumpingcode, you are answering the question. I'll wait some more time to see whether a completely cross-browser solution is proposed.

Comment: Thanks @Danko for observing the non-cross-browser issue.

Comment: @naitoon Unfortunately, there is no cross-browser solution. However, you might be able to do vendor specific styling. This works for IE + Chrome, and there are alternatives for getting it to work in Firefox so could have a Firefox rule. What are you using to render your HTML?

Comment: @jumpingcode I don't understand your question. Do you mean template rendering?

Comment: @jumpingcode I'm using IE9 but it´s a great jump to get a complete solution

Comment: @naitoon Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: BTW, @KenB answer has a reference to a an answer where they are able to style a select box in Firefox.

Comment: @naitoon I've seen, but like I said, you'd need to write a rule specific to Firefox.

Comment: @naitoon What template rendering are you using?

Comment: @jumpingcode currently I'm not using one (I think I'll finish by using Django's default template engine), but I see where you're heading. That can be a great solution if the choices are known at rendering time (this is currently the case). I didn't think about that before.

Comment: @naitoon I was thinking of you could have logic within the template to count the options, and then render a span or select based on this.

Comment: This is a really complicated way to go about it; why not just change the select into a span?

Comment: @jumpingcode I was also thinking about that. I'll evaluate that.

Comment: @KenB It is an overly complicated solution

Comment: @KenB yes, and actually I'll take that approach (replacing select by span and vice-versa). My question was just to know whether another approach was possible. That's all.

Comment: @jumpingcode it's 1 line of code (3 lines if you count looping through the `<span>`s and checking how many children they have). That's doesn't seem too complicated to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSS functionality to determine how many options a select has; if that's the only check you're using, "Does it have multiple options?", then you're going to require some JavaScript.

In general, it's really hard to properly style a `<select>` with CSS, especially in a cross-browser way. See [How to remove the arrow from a  tag in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox) for another user's struggle to do a similar thing. His solution might work for you, but it involves modifying the HTML, and if you're going to do that anyway, you might as well change it to a `<span>`.

## EDIT:

Didn't realize you were also looking for a JavaScript solution. This is the simplest way to do it, and should be as cross-browser as jQuery:

```
$("select").each(function(i, elem){
    if ($(this).children().length == 1) {
        this.outerHTML = "<span>"+this.innerHTML+"</span>";
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SfVp9/3/

Comment: I enjoyed the reference you gave. Thanks @KenB.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no crossbrowser solution for CSS styling of SELECT. And that is why so many solutions maid with converting SPAN to SELECT-like object on the page.

Comment: Could you give some references?

Comment: For example you can use JQueryUI Autocomplete [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Answer (score 0):

If you give up on a pure CSS solution and decide to go with a combination CSS/JS solution.   Here it is:

```
$("select").each( function(i) {
    if( this.length ==1) {
        var val = $(this).first().val();
        $(this).before("<span>" + val + "</span>");
        $(this).addClass("hidden");
    }
} );
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sberg413/P9r5H/19/)

At this point,  you can style the span any way you want by adding a class to it as well.

Comment: I had a CSS+Jquery workaround as I said in the question (which is similar to this one), also involving adding/removing tags. I was interested in a CSS solution, maybe using a bit of Jquery for adding/removing classes, but not changing tags (i.e., not modifying structure, but only style).

Comment: How about something where you have a pre-set <span> already in the DOM with the value of the first option of the select.  Then use js/jquery to just show hide either the select or span depending on the select count?  At that point, it would only be modifying style/visibility.

Comment: It's true. The problem is that when you have two elements, you need to  take care of attributes. The workaround that I already have (cited in the question), has the ability of preserving the attributes of the tags you change. In what you propose, the attributes are lost.