# change type of input element in jquery not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
if($jq(this).text() == "Show") {
    $jq('#password')[0].type = "text";
} else {
    $jq('#password')[0].type = "password";
}
```

In my program, I am changing type of password input field on clicking hide or show password button.

the above code works fine with all the browsers except IE.

anyone plz help me with solution.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using jQuery if you're going to access the raw node like that? you should use `$("#password").attr("type", "text");`

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery#

Answer (score 0):

Try

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
if($jq(this).text() == "Show") {
    $jq('#password').attr("type","text");
} else {
    $jq('#password').attr("type","password");
}
```

or better use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
if($jq(this).text() == "Show") {
    $jq('#password').prop("type","text");
} else {
    $jq('#password').prop("type","password");
}
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)