# How to replace in a Html `table`, the first `th` Html tag by `td` Html tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [jQuery-Visualize](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Visualize) by [Filament Group, Inc.](http://filamentgroup.com/) which produces HTML5 canvas charts driven by HTML table elements.

A requirement of this plugin is, when using a multi-dimensional table, that the first `th` in the `thead` row `tr` needs to be a `td`.

My tables look like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th> <!--This element-->
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But the plugin requires this, otherwise it adds an extra empty classification to the graph, which changes the graph layout:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td><!--Needs to be-->
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/nq57F/) that demonstrates the issue.

How can I use Javascript/jQuery to change the table as described?

Comment: A `<th>` element is a table header, you only really want that as your first row and `<td>` for the rest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery

Comment: I display a chart below and his plugin follows a specific structure of html tag.

Comment: @Jayce for me it's a typical XY problem, you don't ask the right question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `How do I do?` But why would you want to, and what did you try?

Comment: @Xotic750 First, I displayed a chart with html table using javacript pugin like this [link]http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jqueryui-visualize/. He says you **How to use Visualize**. Now, I display with dataTables and I have to manually specify the td tag.

Comment: He is doing the opposite, he uses a header `TH` at the beginning of a row `TR` as a row header, which seems fair. I don't see the sense for your example?

Comment: My example is for the thead tag, do you speak about the tbody tag?

Comment: Yes I was talking about in `tbody`. And the answer you accepted will change all of your row headers in `tbody` back into normal data cells, I don't think you want to do that, do you? But even in `theader` I don't see any need to change the `TH` to `TD`, perhaps better to add a `className` so that you can style it with CSS.

Comment: No, it works well. I looked in the html code generated and everything is good. It changes just in 'thead' tag.  '$('thead tr th:eq(0)')' means the first th tag no?

Comment: I have to change the first td in th otherwise it adds an element more in my chart and everything is shifted.

Comment: Ok, now with a little more detail, that seems to be the requirement for that `visualize` plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/hSEEG/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$('tr th:eq(0)').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<td />").append($(this).contents());
});
```

or easier to understand:

```
$('tr th:first').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<td>" + $(this).html() + "</td>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("th:first").replaceWith("<td/>",{text:"....."});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using jQuery. 
Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("tr:first-child th").each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith('<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>'); 
   });
});
```

Comment: I would use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('tr>th').first().replaceWith('<td></td>');
```

Or if it doesn't work:

```
$('tr>th').first().replaceWith($('<td></td>'));
```

Comment: you then get empty TD

Answer (score 0):

try this way

**HTML CODE:**

```
     <table id="Tbl">
      <tr>
       <th>Hello</th>
       <th>...</th>
       <th>...</th>
       <th>...</th>
       <th>...</th>
       <th>...</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
    $('th:eq(0)').replaceWith('<td>'+$('th:eq(0)').html()+'</td>');
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/LPzs8/6/

*EDIT:corrected the code to make it more precise towards the requirement*

Happy Coding:)