# How can I separate and make a menu with these links in CSS without using unordered lists

Tags: html, css

How can I separate and make a menu with these links in css?  I do not want to use `ul.li`

**Note:** I can't change the html file.

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="navigacion">
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">About</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">History</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Services</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @AlexPrinceton he can't even change the HTML, so looks like he's stuck.

Comment: because the list easier and more convenient

Comment: @AlexPrinceton he said he can't change the HTML. (for whatever reason)

Comment: well this code and how it will implement if he can not change the html

Comment: if you can't change the HTML intiallly, you can still use script to add elements **dynamically**.

Comment: this is a project from my school and i am stuck here with the css .But the html code is this i dont know what to do ideas .. ?? i have search everywhere and they are using the list ul. i know that way of solving this but i cant make changes to this html file... ideas ?

Comment: body
{
 background: brown;
}

a
{
 color: white;
}

p:first-line{
 background-color: magenta;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

p
{
 line-height: 30px;
}

span
{
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#navigacija
{
 padding-left: 20px;
 width: 800px;
 margin: 20px auto;
}

.topNaviagationLink
{
 display: inline-block;
 background: maroon;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
} 

.topNaviagationLink a
{
 line-height: 40px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**your answer are here:**
just change my styles.

http://codepen.io/leandroruel/pen/oyjhK

HTML:

```
 <div id="navigacion">
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">About</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">History</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Services</a></div>
        <div class="topNaviagationLink"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigacion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#navigacion .topNaviagationLink {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#navigacion .topNaviagationLink a {
  font-family: arial;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#navigacion .topNaviagationLink a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
 #navigacion div {display:inline-block;padding:5px;background:#fafafa}
```

Comment: why the downvote? is there anything more you can do with css, as the OP specifically mentioned?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you're looking to change the divs to ul/li but you don't have the ability to edit the HTML... (for whatever reason...)... you can change the elements with jQuery which has been answered here - [how to change an element type using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want a horizontal menu, with evenly spaced menu items, you can change the `display` to be set like a `table`. The fiddle below is a full width horizontal menu with evenly spaced targets for each `.topNaviagationLink` container. If you don't want the menu items to be evenly spaced, remove the `width: 1%;` from `.topNaviagationLink`.

**CSS**

```
#navigacion { 
    display: table; 
}
.topNaviagationLink {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
}
.topNaviagationLink > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2wEu/)