# How to use jquery/javascript to replace dom tag types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

EDIT: I have a RadEditor control and want to build a filter that replaces tag types like <del>...<\del> with <s>...<\s>.  See docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/… where getHtmlContent provides an incoming param a to function with which I want to return the result.

Looking at the answers here...  [how to change an element type using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery), how to use this referenced work to work on incoming parameter 'a' of wrapper function 'r' for return by another function.  For example, I have...

```
function replaceTagType(a, b, c) {
   var newContent;

   /* where 'a' is the target content, 'b' is the target tag type (i.e. <b>)
      and 'c' is the new tag type (i.e. <u>).  What to put here that uses
      above referenced work in "how to change an element type using jquery"
      to assign the results to newContent ? */

   return newContent;
}
```

So if a = "<b>test</b>", resultant var newContent = "<u>test</u>"

Comment: cant you replace <b>test</b> by <u>test</u> ?

Comment: Parse `a`, apply solution in the linked question and convert the element back to HTML?

Comment: I think incoming param a is DOM.  Context:  I have a RadEditor control and want to build a filter that replaced tag types like <del> with <s>.  See http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/managing-content/content-filters where getHtmlContent provides the incoming param a to function with which I want to return the result.

Comment: @FelixKling ok.  What does that look like? (thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. find all `<b>`,
2. get plain text (winthout html tags) by `text()` function
3. get parent element
4. create new `<u>` element with text from `<b>`
5. replace content of parent element by `html()` function

Code:

```
$.parseHTML(a).find(b).each(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    t.parent().html($("<"+c+">").text(t.text()));
});
```

Comment: Where is use of incoming param a ?

Comment: `a` is a string.  A string does not have a `.find()` method.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
var a = $("div").html(); 
//console.log(a);
a=a.replace('<u>', '<b>');
a=a.replace('</u>', '</b>');
$("div").html(a);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fopuxe57/