# changing from <h3> to <h1> in the table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on sharepoint page. I dont have control html generate. so I am writing jquery for manupulation.

I am trying to change `<h3>` to `<h1>`. How to do that?

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
        <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Thank you</nobr>
        </h3>
    </td>
```

I tried this

```
     $('table.ms-formtable > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) h3').replaceWIth(function() {
            return $("<h1>", {
                "class", this.className,
                html: $(this).html();
            });
});
```

But did not work

Comment: how to change an element type using jquery:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: You have a typo: `.replaceWIth(` should be `.replaceWith(`

Comment: `replaceWIth` should be `replaceWith`

Answer (score 1):

Function names are case-sensitive (note `replaceWIth` vs. `replaceWith`):

```
$('table.ms-formtable > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) h3').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<h1>', {
        'class': this.className,
        'html':  this.innerHTML
    });
});
```

Also note that I have replaced the `,` after your `class` property with the correct colon (`:`) literal. Finally, you had a misplaced `;` literal in the `html` definition of the return object. The above snippet should suffice and work as expected now.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0x38az7n/)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to first get the HTML and then replace by using [JQuery Method replaceWith()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=replaceWith) it something like that:

```
var target = $('table.ms-formtable > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) h3');
target.replaceWith($('<h1 class="'+target.attr('class')+'">' + target.innerHTML + '</h1>'));
```

Comment: This will not return the `class` attribute of the existing `<h3>` element.