# How to replace/change Html element using jquery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here i am trying to change the Html element 
i.e `<div>....</div>` to `<h2>.....<h2>`.

HTML is like

```html
<div>
  <a class=" ClassName" href="javascript: {}" onclick="EnsureScriptParams()" onmouseup="this.blur();">
    <div class="ms-displayInlineBlock" id="ctl00_ctl41_g_8dbdb3cb_6fcb_4641_96f9_04df9c6ac8791">Text1</div>
    <div class="ms-ref-downarrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class=" ClassName" href="javascript: {}" onclick="EnsureScriptParams()" onmouseup="this.blur();">
    <div class="ms-displayInlineBlock" id="ctl00_ctl41_g_8dbdb3cb_6fcb_4641_96f9_04df9c6ac8792">Text2</div>
    <div class="ms-ref-downarrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class=" ClassName" href="javascript: {}" onclick="EnsureScriptParams()" onmouseup="this.blur();">
    <div class="ms-displayInlineBlock" id="ctl00_ctl41_g_8dbdb3cb_6fcb_4641_96f9_04df9c6ac8793">Text3</div>
    <div class="ms-ref-downarrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

and here is script code

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
    $('.ClassName').each(function() {
        var id= $(this)[0].children[0].id;
        if(id != null || id != "") {
            $(this)[0].children[0].outerHTML.replace("div", "h2")
        }
    });
});
```

but this seems not working.

Comment: Add HTML also to make it more easy to understand

Comment: You could use .parent then save the innerHTML of that parent.  Go one more parent up, delete the innerHTML (the div), then append that DOM element with the desired h2, and fill the content of the h2 with the saved innerHTML.

Comment: javascript is case sensitive. That means that the selector `$('.className')` will never match classes like `class=" ClassName"`  only because the upper `C`

Comment: That's just a typo here, in my code i have passed proper class name

Comment: Use `innerHTML` instead of `outerHTML`

Comment: This is a duplicate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ClassName').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this).children().eq(0);
        var id = $this.get(0).id;
        if(id != null || id != "") {
            $this.replaceWith('<h2>'+$this.get(0).outerHTML+'</h2>')
        }
    });
});
```

This replace the div to h2

Comment: Thank you soooo much sir @Marc Puigventós Sanz

Answer (score 1):

A. That's because `outerHTML` is property, so you need to assign it some value.

```js
$('.ClassName').each(function() {
  var id = $(this)[0].children[0].id;
  if (id != null || id != "") {
  console.log($(this)[0].children[0].outerHTML);
    $(this)[0].children[0].outerHTML = $(this)[0].children[0].outerHTML.replace("div", "h2");
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

h2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class=" ClassName" href="javascript: {}" onclick="EnsureScriptParams()" onmouseup="this.blur();">
  <div class="ms-displayInlineBlock" id="ctl00_ctl41_g_8dbdb3cb_6fcb_4641_96f9_04df9c6ac8793">Text3</div>
  <div class="ms-ref-downarrow"></div>
</a>
```

B. Use `replace` with Regex so it will replace all of the instances:

```
.replace(/div/g, "h2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can incorporate some custom jQuery to reduce your business logic. You just need to search for divs that have an ID attribute set.

```js
(function($) {
  // Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20469901
  $.replaceTag = function(currentElem, newTagObj, keepProps) {
    var $currentElem = $(currentElem), $newTag = $(newTagObj).clone(), newTag;
    if (keepProps) {
      newTag = $newTag[0];
      newTag.id = currentElem.id;
      newTag.className = currentElem.className;
      $.extend(newTag.classList, currentElem.classList);
      $.extend(newTag.attributes, currentElem.attributes);
    }
    $currentElem.wrapAll($newTag).contents().unwrap();
    return this;
  };
  $.fn.replaceTag = function(newTagObj, keepProps) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $.replaceTag(this, newTagObj, keepProps);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ClassName').find('div[id]').replaceTag('<h2>', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="ClassName" href="javascript: {}"
      onclick="EnsureScriptParams()" onmouseup="this.blur();">
    <div class="ms-displayInlineBlock" 
        id="ctl00_ctl41_g_8dbdb3cb_6fcb_4641_96f9_04df9c6ac8791">Text1</div>
    <div class="ms-ref-downarrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="ClassName" href="javascript: {}"
      onclick="EnsureScriptParams()" onmouseup="this.blur();">
    <div class="ms-displayInlineBlock" 
        id="ctl00_ctl41_g_8dbdb3cb_6fcb_4641_96f9_04df9c6ac8792">Text2</div>
    <div class="ms-ref-downarrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="ClassName" href="javascript: {}"
      onclick="EnsureScriptParams()" onmouseup="this.blur();">
    <div class="ms-displayInlineBlock" 
        id="ctl00_ctl41_g_8dbdb3cb_6fcb_4641_96f9_04df9c6ac8793">Text3</div>
    <div class="ms-ref-downarrow"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```