# Renaming a Node in XML using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am struck in renaming a Node in XML using Javascrip/Jquery.

I tried using renameNode.. But it's not supported in none of the standard browsers i.e., Chrome, Mozilla etc

The requirement is as follows:

I have the following tree structure:

```
<attribute>
<basic_attribute>Some text</basic_Attribute>
</attribute>
```

Want it to rename as :

```
<attribute>
<symbolic_name>Some text</symbolic_name>
</attribute>
```

A small hint would work fine for me.

Comment: What jQuery code have you tried?

Comment: I didn't tried in Jquery. I tried in Javascript the follwoing

if(xmldoc.childNodes[0].childNodes[0]== "basic_Attribute"){
xmldoc.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].renameNode("symbolic_Name",null,"basicAttribute");
}

Comment: @Brijesh See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998357/javascript-how-to-change-a-nodes-name